# Cannot use class from TSMessage library imported via cocoaPods

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I have installed cocoapods in a swift project and installed [TSMessage](https://github.com/KrauseFx/TSMessages) through it. No problem there, but when I try to use it with this instruction:

`TSMessage.showNotificationWithTitle("Success Notification !!!", type: .Success)`

I get the error :

> Use of unresolved identifier 'TSMessage'

I include it like this in my bridging header:
`#import <TSMessages/TSMessage.h>`

Comment: The exemple is in objective c so it doesn't really help me for a swift project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I finally found the answer in [this article](http://rogueleaderr.com/post/115372471213/unresolved-identifier-in-swift-when-importing), you have to add `import TSMessages` at the top of the file where you want to use this class